# Can't create Color object in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter and going through a **charts_flutter** tutorial. I am trying to create a Color object as defined in the tutorial, however, I am stuck on a compile error. The documentation in the tutorial defines creating a color as follows:

```
Color(0xFF3366cc) //causes error
```

However, when I try this, I get the following error when trying to build:

```
Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
```

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:charts_common/common.dart';
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class GaugeLineChart extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _GaugeLineChartState createState() => _GaugeLineChartState();
}

class _GaugeLineChartState extends State<GaugeLineChart> {

  List<charts.Series<GaugeFlowReading, dynamic>> _flowSeries;

  _getReadingData() {
    List<GaugeFlowReading> flows = [];
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      flows.add(GaugeFlowReading(i * 1000, DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(hours: i)), Color(0xffb74093))); // error on Color object here
    }

    _flowSeries.add(
      charts.Series(
        data: flows,
        domainFn: (GaugeFlowReading reading, _) => reading.timestamp,
        measureFn: (GaugeFlowReading reading, _) => reading.flow,
      )
    );

  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text("*CHART GOES HERE*"));
  }
}

class GaugeFlowReading {
  int flow;
  DateTime timestamp;
  Color color;
  GaugeFlowReading(this.flow, this.timestamp, this.color);
}
```

I've been unable to find an answer this question so far. Can anyone clarify why this is happening or help out with this?

Comment: do you a have a complete code or where do you use the Color? are you just creating it inside a class parameter, or just a final color?

Comment: there is no problem with your Color declaration: https://gist.github.com/HosseinYousefi/4ceb2a982d1a9fad0dc5f9b63a9988c2, please provide more of your code/error message to figure out the problem.

Comment: the code snippet still doesn't seem to have any problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried your code, and the error does exists.

As an alternative you may try this.

```
Color.fromHex(code: "b74093")
```

This also seems to be a conflicting problem with the packages you used.

[image]

When I commented the import of charts_common, the error you encountered was gone.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems the package `import 'package:charts_common/common.dart';` has its own class Color, you can change it to

`import 'package:charts_common/common.dart' hide Color;`

or

`import 'package:charts_common/common.dart' as charts_common;`

so the compiler detects you're indeed using the Color class fo the flutter framework